# Can anything end bleeding damage early?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, when a player is set on fire, most healing will put the player out so that she will not suffer anymore damage.  I wonder if the same is true of bleeding.

Is there anyway to stop bleeding damage early, short of death?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Picking up a health pack should now stop ongoing bleed damage (there was a period where it did not).

Unlike Afterburn, which can be put out with healing (from medi-guns and dispensers at least) , bleed effects will always tick for the full duration in the absence of health kits.

[The wiki has more information.](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Bleed)